# Detecting unicode private use area (PUA) characters with Java/Kotlin from File

Tags: java, kotlin, unicode

Is there any proper way to identify Unicode private use area (PUA) characters in Java/Kotlin?

Some background, we are using PDF conversion tool, which doesn't support PUA characters. Thus we require to identify any PUA character available in the file.
So what's a non-hacky, reliable way to detect PUA characters?

Comment: In Kotlin you can check whether your character is `in CharCategory.PRIVATE_USE`.

Comment: @skomisa so I need to read the file character by character? I may have Docx or PDFs files as well. any samples?

Comment: [1] Your question is asking for a way to identify PUA characters, so I don't see how you can avoid checking _"character by character"_. What alternative strategy did you have in mind? [2] As an alternative to using Java/Kotlin APIs, you could use a regex to filter out characters in any of the three ranges defined as PUAs (U+E000 to U+F8FF, U+F0000 to U+FFFFD and U+100000 to +10FFFD). I don't know whether you consider that approach _"proper"_ and _"non-hacky"_, but it would be reliable, and fairly simple to code. [3] Update your  question to specify all file types to be processed...

Comment: ...[4] As an alternative to a regex, in Java you could process the file as a stream, and use a `.filter()` within the stream processing.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two "proper" ways to do it:

```
int cp = ...     // a Unicode codepoint represented as an int

if (Character.isType(cp) == Character.PRIVATE_USE) {
    // ...
}

if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(cp) == Character.UnicodeBlock.PRIVATE_USE_AREA) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So I need to read my files character by character then decide? I might have Docx or PDFs to work with. Is there any samples I should look?